# API testing in postman giving product is not a contructor error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on REST API with Node, express and MongoDB. I am using mongoose. I am testing API on Postman. When I am hitting post request on products endpoint I'm getting error `"message": "Product is not a constructor"` and the morgan logger is giving me status 500. The tutorial I'm referring to is little old. Here is my code.

```js
// products.js file
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    }); 
    product.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    res.status(201).json({      
        message: 'Handling post request to /products',
        createdProduct: product
    });
});
```

```js
// product,js schema file
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number
});

exports.modules = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

```js
// app.js file
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shop', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly exporting the product model. Update the export line in `product.js` to this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Read more about `module.expots` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)/